# yum install package "Error unpacking rpm package xxxxx cpio:xxxx"

Tags: python, yum, supervisord

Since I send `Ctrl+C` to the command line with the `yum update` running on my server(centos6.7), the yum cannot install packages for days.

I was suggested to run `yum-complete-transaction`, but I could not install the package yum-utils with the same error.

Someone told me to check the **attrs of `/usr/bin`, `/usr/local/bin`, I know the i but what the upper I meanning?

### attrs

`lsattr /usr`

```
-------------e- /usr/src
----------I--e- /usr/include
-------------e- /usr/libexec
-------------e- /usr/local
----------I--e- /usr/lib
-------------e- /usr/share
-------------e- /usr/.
----------I--e- /usr/bin
-------------e- /usr/etc
```

### yum error

```
[root@localhost ~]# yum install supervisor
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
epel/metalink                                                                                                                                                      |  12 kB     00:00     
 * base: mirror.lax.hugeserver.com
 * epel: linux.mirrors.es.net
 * extras: mirror.keystealth.org
 * updates: mirror.spro.net
base                                                                                                                                                               | 3.7 kB     00:00     
extras                                                                                                                                                             | 3.4 kB     00:00     
updates                                                                                                                                                            | 3.4 kB     00:00     
Setting up Install Process
Resolving Dependencies
There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.
The program yum-complete-transaction is found in the yum-utils package.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package supervisor.noarch 0:2.1-9.el6 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==========================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                        Arch                                       Version                                         Repository                                Size
==========================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 supervisor                                     noarch                                     2.1-9.el6                                       epel                                     292 k

Transaction Summary
==========================================================================================================================================================================================
Install       1 Package(s)

Total download size: 292 k
Installed size: 1.1 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
supervisor-2.1-9.el6.noarch.rpm                                                                                                                                    | 292 kB     00:00     
Running rpm_check_debug
Running Transaction Test
Transaction Test Succeeded
Running Transaction
  Installing : supervisor-2.1-9.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                            1/1 
Error unpacking rpm package supervisor-2.1-9.el6.noarch
error: unpacking of archive failed on file /etc/rc.d/init.d/supervisord;5717010a: cpio: open
  Verifying  : supervisor-2.1-9.el6.noarch                                                                                                                                            1/1 

Failed:
  supervisor.noarch 0:2.1-9.el6                                                                                                                                                           

Complete!
```

Comment: Instead of answer, but for future visitors: [In my case](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/741937/213987) there was insufficient space on `/boot` to unpack kernel.